How terminates a python process with queues ? + Bug with size of queues?
I'm just starting out with multiprocessing in Python.
I use multiprocessing.queues in my program that I pass from process to process.
The problem is that when I use myprocess.join(), it only terminates when the queue I'm writing to is empty.
So I'm wondering what the reason is, why it's built that way and how to get around it. I can empty all my queues in my main process, but I'd like it better.
Bug part :
What I explained to you is the bahaviour for queues with more than 100 elements.
In my example if you put a list of initial data of 100 : in range(100) the p4.join() will be called as expected, but if you put 1000 or more it stops working as I explained. So I'm a little bit lost.
EDIT : The bug appears at a input data size of 533 or 534 elements
Thanks,
Here a small example to show you.


import random
import multiprocessing
import time


def process1(data, queue1):
    for item in data:
        queue1.put(item)

    queue1.put(None)


def process2(queue1, queue2):
    while True:
        item = queue1.get()
        if item is None:
            queue2.put(None)
            break
        queue2.put(item * 2)


def process3(queue2, queue3):
    while True:
        item = queue2.get()
        if item is None:
            queue3.put(None)
            break
        queue3.put(item * 2)


def process4(queue3, queue4):
    while True:
        item = queue3.get()
        if item is None:
            queue4.put(None)
            print("None received")
            break
        queue4.put(item * 2)
    print("End process4")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_time = time.time()

    data = [random.randint(1, 10000) for _ in range(10000)]

    queue1 = multiprocessing.Queue()
    queue2 = multiprocessing.Queue()
    queue3 = multiprocessing.Queue()
    queue4 = multiprocessing.Queue()

    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=process1, args=(data, queue1))
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=process2, args=(queue1, queue2))
    p3 = multiprocessing.Process(target=process3, args=(queue2, queue3))
    p4 = multiprocessing.Process(target=process4, args=(queue3, queue4))

    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p3.start()
    p4.start()
    print("Proc started")

    p1.join()
    print("p1 join")
    p2.join()
    print("p2 join")
    p3.join()
    print("p3 join")
    p4.join()
    print("p4 join")

    results = []
    print("While loop")
    while True:
        item = queue4.get()
        if item is None:
            break
        results.append(item)

    end_time = time.time()

    print(end_time - start_time)





A multiprocessing.Queue has a maximum size, to avoid consuming all your memory if the producer side is running faster than the consumer side.  If a process tries to enqueue more data than that, it's not going to be able to finish unless something is actually removing items from the queue.

Oh ok thanks @jasonharper
I try to set a max size in my queue but get the same problem. The max size is not reach
queue1 = multiprocessing.Queue(2000)

The issue is described in https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-programming in section "Joining processes that use queues".
The basic idea is the process will wait before terminating until all the buffered items are fed by the "feeder" thread to the underlying pipe.
import multiprocessing
import random
import time


def process1(data, queue1):
    for item in data:
        queue1.put(item)

    queue1.put(None)


def process2(queue1, queue2):
    while True:
        item = queue1.get()
        if item is None:
            queue2.put(None)
            break
        queue2.put(item * 2)


def process3(queue2, queue3):
    while True:
        item = queue2.get()
        if item is None:
            queue3.put(None)
            break
        queue3.put(item * 2)


def process4(queue3, queue4):
    # calling queue4.cancel_join_thread() will correctly terminate the process
    # queue4.cancel_join_thread()
    # BUT not all items are put into the queue4 (rest are discarded)

    # see https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-programming
    # section "Joining processes that use queues"

    while True:
        item = queue3.get()
        if item is None:
            queue4.put(None)
            print("None received")
            break
        queue4.put(item * 2)
    print("End process4")
    print(queue4.qsize())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_time = time.time()

    data = [random.randint(1, 10000) for _ in range(10000)]

    queue1 = multiprocessing.Queue()
    queue2 = multiprocessing.Queue()
    queue3 = multiprocessing.Queue()
    queue4 = multiprocessing.Queue()

    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=process1, args=(data, queue1))
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=process2, args=(queue1, queue2))
    p3 = multiprocessing.Process(target=process3, args=(queue2, queue3))
    p4 = multiprocessing.Process(target=process4, args=(queue3, queue4))

    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p3.start()
    p4.start()
    print("Proc started")

    p1.join()
    print("p1 join")
    p2.join()
    print("p2 join")
    p3.join()
    print("p3 join")

    # don't call p4.join() here
    # p4.join()
    # print("p4 join")

    results = []
    print("While loop")
    while True:
        item = queue4.get()
        if item is None:
            break
        results.append(item)

    end_time = time.time()

    # call p4.join() here instead:
    p4.join()
    print("p4 join")

    print(end_time - start_time)

Prints:
Proc started
p1 join
None received
End process4
10001
p2 join
p3 join
While loop
p4 join
0.1303730010986328


Thanks for your explanation ! Yes I do that too without to kniow why yesterday.
Sadly I can't upvote your solution because of my lack of xp here but thanks !

However do you why the behaviour is different according to the size of Queue ? (Data input in the example) As I explained in my edit
Thanks,
